# Angular: keep observable alive until another one happens

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a `ModalComponent` which is created dynamically via a service.
In this component I'm emitting two events (`onModalClose` and `onModalInputChanged`) because in this modal I have a form and each time I change a value I emit this value.
the problem I'm facing here is that when I subscribe to the `onModalInputChanged` I get the first eitted value after that the observale somehow is closed and I no longer receiving changed values
so what I want exactly is to keep the `onModalInputChanged` alive and keep getting changed values until I emit the `onModalClose` event.
**And this is what I have done so far:**
`ModalComponent`:

```
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output('onModalClose') onModalClose: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output('onModalInputChanged') onModalInputChanged: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  inputChanged(value){// let 's say this is called when an input is changed
     this.onModalInputChanged.emit(value);
  }

  close(){ this.onModalClose.emit() }
}
```

The service that creates this component dynamically:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ModalService {
private _container: ViewContainerRef;
  private component: ComponentRef<ModalComponent>;

  constructor(private _factoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  setRootViewContainerRef(viewContainerRef) {
    this._container = viewContainerRef
  }

  openModal(): Observable<any>{
    const factory = this._factoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ModalComponent)
    this.component = factory.create(this._container.parentInjector)
    this._container.insert(this.component.hostView);
    // subscribe to on close event and remove the component's DOM from the document
    this.component.instance.onModalClose.subscribe(() => this.component.destroy());
    // here I receive the emitted value and returned it as observable so I can subscribe to it from another component
    return this.component.instance.onModalInputChanged.map(value => value).first();
  }
}
```

Now from **any other component** I want to open this modal and subscribe to emitted values until the modal is closed:

```
export class SomeComponent{

  constructor(private _modalService: ModalService){}

  openModalAndWaitForChanges(){
       this._modalService.openModal().subscribe(value => {
          console.log(value);// I get this value only the first time after that the observable does not emit any value
       });
  }

}
```

Comment: I think it's because of first() operator , after the first value got emitted the source observable will complete and it's longer emit the value

Comment: @Code-EZ yes you were right, but soes the observable stay alive if I close the component and destroy it ?